# Can "control" of EE licenses be transferred?

Tags: license

We took over a site from another agency, but they still technically have the only access to the license for the site. Is there any way to have EllisLabs transfer it? Or just enter the license # under our  own account as belonging to us now?

I am completely clueless if there's even a way to do this, and didn't see a way to just quick-contact EllisLabs without being charged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be a quick email to EllisLab sales department. The previous agency, however, will have to initiate the transfer in the first place as they own it. Ask them to email sales@ellislab.com, tell them what account to transfer it to, and EL usually resolves it in a couple days.

It should NOT incur additional fees as you're just taking over the ownership. That being said, the ownership should probably be best transferred to the CLIENT as they should own it perpetually, NOT the agency. You would get the client to create an EllisLab.com account and then get the previous agency to transfer that license to them. So in the event they change another vendor or whatever, the license is still theirs.

Comment: Yup, I've done this in the past myself. Email Ellislab and they can transfer (once initiated by the current license holder) to a new user account whether that is yours or the clients.

Comment: In the email you need to have the agency specify the license number in question, and the transferring recipients email and EllisLab.com username to speed things up.

Comment: Thanks guys :) I will get right on that! The reason it was being transferred to us instead of the client is, they don't do management of their site, we do. It's probably still a good idea I guess to have it under their account, but I wouldn't necessarily be able to access it.

Comment: Well, if they give you the username/password you should be good to go. :) That's what my clients do with me.